# Specific differential equation formatting

Tags: differential-equations

I'm solving the following engineering exercise:

[image: 5.14]

Knowing so, I created the following script:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
zeta = 0.04; 
theta = -π/2; 
r = 0.5; 
q = 0.15;
omega = 2.0;

sol = 
  NDSolveValue[
    {th''[t] + 2 zeta th'[t] + (1 - omega^2 Cos[omega t]) Sin[th[t]] == 0,
     th[0] = theta, th'[0] = r},
    th, {t, 0, 300}]
```

However, it has given me an error and cannot be evaluated. I suspect it might be regarding the t variable within the cosine. How should I format this?

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
zeta = 0.04; 
theta = -π/2; 
r = 0.5; 
q = 0.15;
omega = 2.0;
sol = 
  NDSolveValue[
    {th''[t] + 2 zeta th'[t] + (1 - omega^2 Cos[omega t]) Sin[th[t]] == 0,  
     th[0] == theta, th'[0] == r}, 
    th, {t, 0, 300}]
```

The problem was with the initial conditions. They need an **==**